# Can I use my iPod classic to store photos for my Canon 5D MkII?

Tags: photos, camera, storage, ipod-classic

I have an 80GB iPod classic. I am going on a trip and I have only the iPod, my iPhone, and my iPad. I want to use the iPod to store photos.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You need the discontinued "iPod" camera connector. (not to be confused with the iOS iPad camera connector)

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TA38187

They are for sale on Amazon (and of course at local thrift shops and electronics shops worldwide).

[http://www.amazon.com/Apple-Camera-Connector-iPod-White/dp/B000KIRGF4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KIRGF4)

Comment: I just bought one on Amazon. Used. Thanks for the reply!